# tar works on cmd but not work on bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line, tar

Windows tar command works on cmder.

```
tar -zxvf D:\backup\a.tar.gz
```

But when I add it to bat file, it doesn't work. I tried these versions

```
call tar -zxvf D:\backup\a.tar.gz
tar -zxvf D:\backup\a.tar.gz
call tar -zxvf ./a.tar.gz
tar -zxvf ./a.tar.gz
```

no one worked and I get an error

> 'tar' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

Comment: is the `tar` executable in the same directory as the batch file?

Comment: no, but when I run it from cmd, it works

Comment: Probably you the command prompt window is opened in the directory where the tar is?   In the batch try to put line like `set "path=%path%;C:\tar_executable_directory"`

Comment: I run command prompt from the same directory as bat file. 
I am new on widows, so I cant find where is tar_executable.

Comment: also set "path=%path%" dont help

Comment: Without the batch file no one can answer for sure. And [tag:cmd] and [tag:cmder] are very different things. Don't use `cmder` when talking about `cmd`. `set "path=%path%"` obviously do "nothing", you need `set "path=%path%;path\to\tar.exe"`. The path to tar.exe can be found by running `where tar`

Answer (score 0):

call tar from the directory
e.g. tar is in the same folder as your batch file

```
"%~dp0tar" -zxvf "D:\backup\a.tar.gz"
```

otherwise i suggest you use the full path for tar within quotes.

```
"C:\users\yourname\Desktop\tar" -zxvf "D:\backup\a.tar.gz"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My issue was caused because I created a variable called path in my batch file which overwrote the windows path variable which contains the directory where tar is stored. Maybe you did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. First set the current path to the directory were the zip file is located, then issue the tar on the file.

```
cd /d "F:/some/path/to/zip" & tar -zf <file_name>.zip
```

Comment: he said that tar is not defined on his machine, how do you want to use it like this? you should carefully read the question

Answer (score -1):

Use relative paths or if you need absolute paths then use forward slash `/` instead of backslash `\` (e.g. D:/backup/a.tar.gz)

It doesn't take anyone a second to try it, and it is simply the solution that worked for me after many trials.

Comment: Windows commands always accept backslash. Only a few commands accept forward slash /

Comment: the OP said `tar works on cmd` so obviously tar accepts the same backslash path without problem. In fact programs compiled with MSYS2 or Cygwin also accept backslash as the separator even though POSIX uses slash instead. They don't care about that because the path is just passed to Win32 API without modification. The reason must be something else

Comment: Thanks @phuclv, to me it doesn't matter what anyone say when I try 10s of times different solutions and only forward-slash works